# How to finish SplashScreen from stack in react-native-navigation

Tags: android, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am new in react-native an I am working on a **react-native project**, I use [react-native-navigation](http://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation) from **wix** and didn't find any solution for how to clear the **SplashScreen** or any Screen from stack which I don't need to go back again.

I use this to navigate after 2 second.

```
componentWillMount(){
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            this.props.navigator.push({
                screen: 'SampleApp.LoginScreen',
            })
        }, 2000
    );
}
```

and this in my **index.js**

```
export function registerScreens() {
    Navigation.registerComponent('SampleApp.SplashScreen', () => SplashScreen);
    Navigation.registerComponent('SampleApp.LoginScreen', () => LoginScreen);
}
```

Please help me to find the solution where I need to call `finish()` or is there something else. Thanks in advance

Comment: try to read official docs on [official website](http://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));
}



onNavigatorEvent(event) {
    switch (event.id) {
        case 'willAppear':
            this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
            this.backHandler.remove();
            break;
        case 'willDisappear':
            this.backPressed = 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

handleBackPress = () => {
    if (this.backPressed && this.backPressed > 0) {
        this.props.navigator.popToRoot({ animated: false });
        return false;
    }

    this.backPressed = 1;
    this.props.navigator.showSnackbar({
        text: 'Press one more time to exit',
        duration: 'long',
    });
    return true;
}
```